# Blocking meme photos on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I only follow a handful of close family members on Facebook, and I do it to share status updates as we live far away. But when I log in all I can see is (not)funny meme photos that have been "liked" by someone I follow, which is annoying.

The photos are originally posted by fake accounts with names like "I hate how spiders just sit on the wall like they pay rent", but when they are "liked" by someone I follow, they show up my stream. I'm sick of them.

How can I block these pictures from my stream without blocking the person I follow?

Answer (score 1):

In your Facebook News Feed, hover over the name of your friend and then the word **Friends**, and click on **Settings...**.   If you do not want your friend's comments and likes to appear in your News Feed, uncheck **Comments and Likes**.

[image: Friends menu]
[image: Friends settings menu]

Alternatively, choose **Hide...** from the menu in the upper right corner of the post and choose one of the options that are shown.

[image: Hide menu]
[image: Hide result]

Comment: The first answer is out of date now, as Facebook have removed the Newsfeed options shown in your screenshot. The "hide post" option still works, but that only works after you have seen the image already. In order to pre-emptively hide them, you need to use the solution I offered on this page.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the [**FB Purity** browser add-on](http://www.fbpurity.com), has options that allow you to hide images based on the content of the image. One of its built in image content filtering options is **hide** "**Meme Images**".

1. Get **FB Purity** via the [**FB Purity Website**](http://www.fbpurity.com).
2. Go to any Facebook page.
3. Click the "**FBP**" link in the top navigation bar to open the FB Purity options screen.
4. Click the "**Photo Stories**" heading in the left column of the FB Purity options screen.
5. Tick the Hide "**Meme Image**" option (as shown in the screenshot).
6. Click the "**Save and Close**" button on the FBP options screen, to save the setting.
7. Now when FB Purity detects a "**Meme**" type image, i.e. an image containing text content, it will hide that image from your newsfeed.

**FB Purity** is available for all the major browsers: **Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari** and **Opera**

[image: The FB Purity option that lets you hide "Meme" images from your Facebook newsfeed]

Answer (score 0):

They're called pages, not 'fake profiles'. You can go onto the Page and select the option to block the page.

Comment: Blocking a page does not actually stop posts from that page coming up in your newsfeed. It just stop the page from interacting with your posts and 
liking or replying to your comments. What you might have meant is to use the "hide post" menu at the top right of each post, to select the "hide all posts from this page" option.